# How to convert a date with only a year to a date with the format "Year-Month-Day" in R

Tags: r, date

Sorry for the question, I started using RStudio a month ago and I get confronted to things I've never learned. I checked all the websites, helps and forums possible the past two days and this is getting me crazy.

I got a variable called `Release` giving the date of the release of a song. Some dates are following the format `%Y-%m-%d` whereas some others only give me a Year. 
I'd like them to be all the same but I'm struggling to only modify the observations with the year.

Brief summary in word:

```
11/11/2011
01/06/2011
1974
1970
16/09/2003
```

I've imported the data with :

```
music<-read.csv("music2.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",", encoding = "UTF-8",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And this how I have it in RStudio

```
"2011-11-11" "2011-06-01" "1974" "1970" "2003-09-16"
```

This is an example as I got 2200 obs.

The working code is

```
Modifdates<- ifelse(nchar(music$Release)==4,paste0("01-01-",music$Release),music$Release)
Modifdates
```

I obtain this :

```
"2011-11-11" "2011-06-01" "01-01-1974" "01-01-1970" "2003-09-16"
```

I just would like them to be all with the same format "%Y-%m-%d". How can I do that?

So I tried this

```
as.Date(music$Release,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

But I got NA's where I modified my dates.

Could anyone help?

Comment: You say that the format is `%Y-%m-%d`, but it looks like `%d/%m/%Y` instead. So, you should better add `01/01/`. To detect the only-year values you might check the number of characters with `nchar`: for instance `nchar(music$Release)==4` will detect them so you can add day and month only to them.

Comment: @nicola Yes, when I open the file in word I have "%d/%m/%Y" but when I open it in RStudio, it's %Y-%m-%d ,this is why I used that. 
Honestly, it's all new for me and I don't get anything about what I'm supposed to do with that --"

Comment: Please, read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example It is much easier to answer the question, working with the sample of your data, instead of guessing how your data might look like..

Comment: @utubun I've edited my post. I don't know what else I could tell you...

Comment: @Nigel it's ok, it's just a good practice to give people some data to work with.

Comment: Also try using the great `lubridate` library, that does a lot of work of matching the correct input format for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Using `sub` find occurrences of date consisting from single year (`"(^[0-9]{4}$)"` part), using back-reference substitute it to add `-01-01` at the end of the string (`"\\1-01-01"` part), and finally convert it to the `date` class, using `as.Date()` (`as.Date()` default is `format = "%Y-%m-%d"` so you don't need to specify it):

```
dat <- c("2011-11-11", "2011-06-01", "1974", "1970", "2003-09-16")
```

`dat` class is `character`:

```
as.Date(sub("(^[0-9]{4}$)", "\\1-01-01", dat))

# "2011-11-11" "2011-06-01" "1974-01-01" "1970-01-01" "2003-09-16"
```

`dat` class is `factor`, but `sub` automatically coerce it to the `character` class for you:

```
# dat <- as.factor(dat); dat

# 2011-11-11 2011-06-01 1974       1970       2003-09-16
# Levels: 1970 1974 2003-09-16 2011-06-01 2011-11-11

as.Date(sub("(^[0-9]{4}$)", "\\1-01-01", dat))

# "2011-11-11" "2011-06-01" "1974-01-01" "1970-01-01" "2003-09-16"
```

Comment: As mentioned in comments above, instead of `asDate()` you can call `lubridate::ymd(sub("(^[0-9]{4}$)", "\\1-01-01", dat))` to obtain the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, please try to provide a reproducible example next time so that we can best help you. 
I think here you could use:

```
testdates <- c("1974", "12-12-2012")
betterdates <- ifelse(nchar(testdates)==4,paste0("01-01-",testdates),testdates)
> betterdates
[1] "01-01-1974" "12-12-2012"
```

EDIT: if your vector is factor you should use `as.character.factor` first. If you then want to convert back to factor you can use `as.factor`

EDIT2 : do not convert `as.date` before doing this. Only do it after this modification

Comment: Thank you  @utubun. When I write your code and change the "dat" into my variable, I only get "NA" everywhere...

Comment: Your solution doesn't work either @gpier. 
My variable is a factor not a vector so the "nchar" isn't working 
"Error in nchar(music$Release) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector"

Comment: So convert it to the `character`, or when you read your data (by `read.csv()` I suppose, make `stringsAsFactors = F` inside the `read.csv()` call.

Comment: @utubun, 
Alright, when I had "stringsAsFactors = F" it works, THANK YOU!
The only issue remaining is that now, all my dates in R are written with the format %Y-%m-%d except the ones I just modified %d-%m-%Y
When I change the format with "as.date" they turn into NA again...

Comment: You have to modify the string to paste in order to get the same format for all dates. I followed the data you gave me and I can't guess what your data looks like...

Comment: welcome, if that suits you please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @gpier 
This is what I have
Modifdates<- ifelse(nchar(music$Release)==4,paste0("01-01-",music$Release),music$Release)


Modifdates


as.Date(music$Release,format="%Y-%m-%d")

The first code is working properly but when I convert it in "as.date", NA's return

Comment: How about `as.Date(music$Release,format="%d-%m-%Y")`?

Comment: @gpier It gives me NA's everywhere

Comment: please share your current full code in the question and comment when done

Comment: @gpier Already done above. But here it is. First part is working but when I put as.Date, only got NA
Modifdates<- ifelse(nchar(music$Release)==4,paste0("01-01-",music$Release),music$Release)
Modifdates
as.Date(music$Release,format="%d-%m-%Y")

Comment: And before doing as.Date, I obtain this : "2011-11-11" "2011-06-01" "01-01-1974" "01-01-1970" "2003-09-16" . I just would like them to be all with the same format "%Y-%m-%d". How can I do that?